# JasperReports 5.2 is not working with poi-3.7

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi, nosuchmethod

I am using *JasperReports 5.2* with *Apache poi 3.7* in server lib folder. I don't have any other versions of *poi* in server lib. When I am trying to generate *Excel* report I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getCreationHelper()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper;
```

I can see this method available in this jar file with help of below link.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.7/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.java?av=f

Comment: May be you have several versions of *poi* library in classpath. May be your server application contains another version of this lib

Comment: The *JasperReports API 5.2* is using *org.apache.poi 3.7*

Comment: @AlexK, I had old poi jar contents with different jar name in server lib. I removed it and I am not getting any errors now.

Comment: I'm already posted a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069316/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-poi-hssf-usermodel-hssfsheet-setcolumnwi/68149007#68149007)

Comment: I'm already posted a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069316/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-poi-hssf-usermodel-hssfsheet-setcolumnwi/68149007#68149007), it would be helpful for you.

Comment: You can see the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069316/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-poi-hssf-usermodel-hssfsheet-setcolumnwi/68149007#68149007), it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sufficiently common problem that [the Apache POI FAQ has an entry for it](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006), which [even includes code to work out what's wrong](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)

Basically, somewhere else on your classpath (possibly from your server), there's an older copy of Apache POI. When your code runs, it triggers the loading of the class, and your classloader unhelpfully opts for the older jar, not the newer one.

If you [run the code from the FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006):

```
ClassLoader classloader =
   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource(
         "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("Core POI came from " + path);
```

Then that will tell you where the core of POI is being loaded from. I can virtually guarantee that it won't be the jar you expect... Zap the old POI jars (all of them!), then you should be good to go.

Well, mostly good to go. [Apache POI 3.7 is 3 years old](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.7) so there have been lots of [fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.7), making it worth looking into upgrading!

Comment: There is a jar file in my server with different name but old poi jar contents. I didn't realize this until I ran above four lines of code. I removed that jar file and jasper 5.2 is working with poi 3.7. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can see the appropriate apache poi version by inspecting your relevant maven repo for Jasper.

I happen to be on Jasper 6.1:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0/jasperreports-6.1.0.pom

which points to apache poi 3.10.1.

Without the versions matching, you're likely to experience all sorts of wierdnesses. Yes I made up that word.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **iReport 5.5.0** with the jar below ...

```
poi-3.13.jar
jasperreports-5.0.4.jar
jackson-all-1.9.0.jar
```

**and it works fine...**