# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.setColumnWidth(II)V

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate Jasper Excel report.I am getting the exception like

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.setColumnWidth(II)V
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.setColumnWidth(JRXlsExporter.java:212)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.setColumnWidths(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:654)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportPage(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:527)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:423)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:207)
at com.pagesolutions.controller.ReportingController.doGet(ReportingController.java:177)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Java code

```
if(formatType.matches("XLS")){
            String jrxml = "/home/madhu/report1.jrxml";
            list = (List<Reports>) session.getAttribute("customersList");
            //InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jrxml);
            try {
                //jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml);
                //jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jrxml);
                jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml);
                JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list, true);
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, datasource);
                String output="/home/madhu/reports/report.xls";
                //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, output);
                JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
                exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
                exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, output);
                exporterXLS.exportReport();
                 ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                 String fileName = "report.xls";
                 FileInputStream fileToDownload = new FileInputStream(output);
                 response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName);
                 ByteArrayOutputStream output1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                 int readBytes = 0;
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                 while ((readBytes = fileToDownload.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                     servletOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                 }

                 output1.flush();
                 output1.close();
                 fileToDownload.close();
            } catch (JRException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I already added poi-3.2-FINAL.jar file in my lib but still getting the above exception

Can any one help me please....

Comment: Could you please provide a full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: looks to me like you are calling setColumnWidth with one parameter, while it takes two.

Comment: I given full stack track please chek

Comment: Which version of Jasper Reports are you using? Seems that it's impompatible with used POI version.

Comment: @Stultuske Madhu's code is not calling the particular method, but the Jasper Report Framework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the project builds but you get this error at runtime, it can mean only one thing: you're building and running with different library versions. The version you built against has this method while the one you ran with doesn't. It could have also happened that you have multiple versions on the classpath and the wrong one is loaded first. I don't know how you build your project, but if you're using some kind of dependency manager, analyse the structure for duplicate POI versions. If you're not using any dependency manager... well... make sure manually that libraries match at build- and runtime, but you really should switch to a build tool that does this for you so that Jasper can automatically drag in the correct version it depends on.

**Important note:**
Since Jasper already depends on POI, there's no reason for your project to declare that dependency again. It's only asking for trouble of the variety you're seeing now. You just declare your dependency to Jasper and let your dependency manager drag in the correct version of POI. Somehow, fundamental misunderstanding of dependency management is common even among senior developers.

If, on the other hand, another library you depend on also drags in a different version of POI, you need to either find compatible versions of both third-party libraries (so that they need the same POI), or explicitly​ exclude POI from one of them, cross your fingers and hope for the best.

Comment: @Madhu Maven, Ivy, Gradle, Ant are all great build tools (plus many more...). It would help if you used one.

Comment: He does not compile Jasper reports code, so compiling will work even if there's no appropriate POI version around.

Comment: I was receiving a similar error due to one version of a jar being in the lib folder of my project and another being declared in the pom causing a version "mismatch". No errors show in the project compilation, but it's at runtime as the respondent mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

I just fixed this error on my application. Upgrading to the latest version of POI (3.15 as of this writing) was the WRONG thing to do.

As of Jasperreports 6.3.1, it requires Apache POI 3.10.1. I found this out by looking at the Jasperreports repository POM file, located here:
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/6.3.1/jasperreports-6.3.1.pom

If you are using a different version of Jasper just change to your version in the URL and check the pom file. Search it for POI and it will tell you what version is required.

As soon as I downgraded from POI 3.15 to 3.10.1 my errors went away and I got a lovely .xls file for my efforts. I had been stuck on this for a while and it feels good to have it finally working!

Comment: Why would you even re-declare the dependency on POI? Dependency on Jasper is enough, Maven would have obtained the correct version of POI by itself. By re-declaring the dependency and changing the version, you're​ just asking for trouble.

Comment: @kaqqao POI is an optional dependency for Jasper. It does not automatically import. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0 Also, I am not changing the version, I am making sure to match the version that Jasper is expecting.

Comment: @ScottM I see. Then yes, you need to re-declare it, but matching the version.

Comment: It really helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your Apache POI version to the latest one (the latest stable version is 3.11). Version 3.2 is very old. Current version [contains](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.11/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.java#HSSFSheet.setColumnWidth%28int%2Cint%29) this setColumnWidth(int, int) method which was absent in 3.2 version

Comment: The OP's project only transitively depends on POI. Updating POI just makes running into incompatibilities more likely.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed jar with 'poi-3.11.jar' and 'jxls-reader-1.0.6.jar'

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

and added dependency `3.11` 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JasperReports 6.x.x, please upgrade the apache poi jar version to 4.1.2. I'm using JasperReports 6.13.0 version, this was resolved for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using the JasperReports 5.x.x version, please use a stable version of the apache poi 3.11.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```